# Sequentially filling shapes in canvas using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, canvas

I made a maze application with a route finder.  As it travels along the route, it makes a call to draw the canvas, highlighting each cell en route.  However what ends up happening is it blocks until it has completely finished and then draws to the canvas.  Roughly like so:

```
Path.prototype.travelTo (cell) {
  this.previous = this.cell;
  this.cell = cell;
  this.cell.fill = 'yellow';
  this.maze.draw();
  var choice = findChoice();
  this.travelTo(choice);
};
```

The maze class keeps track of all cells and its draw function loops through each cell, calling the cells own draw function.

I made a quick jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/amctammany/99VVu/) that emulates the problem.
Here it travels from one cell to the next by recursively calling itself via setTimeout. The result is the same, it instantly fills all cells, without even waiting for any amount of time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your jsfiddle, and the first thing I noticed is your setTimeout:

```
window.setTimeout(fillNext(i + 1), 500);
```

But probably you meant to do this:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {fillNext(i + 1)}, 500);
```

---

You should set the `fillNext(i+1)` as a callback to `setTimeout`, 
not use the return value of `fillNext(i+1)` as the argument of `window.setTimeout()`

Comment: Works like a charm for this demo and the actual application.  Thank you.  It's always the simple or small things that are hardest to find.

Comment: No problem, sometimes you stare at a problem too much that you can't see obvious mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Update the following line as given below.Then you can see the animation.

```
  "window.setTimeout(fillNext(i + 1), 500);"  To "window.setTimeout(fillNext, 100,(i + 1));"
```

I have updated the fiddle.You can check it now.

Comment: This also works.  Is there any advantage to this over the above answer?

Comment: I don't think so.In the previous example,we have a anonymous function which in-turn call the following function "fillNext(i + 1)".But in my example we are just calling the function directly.